# EditText: keep hint when focused

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have an `EditText` and I want the hint to stay until the user actually types. By default the hint is already hidden when the user focuses the `EditText`, before he starts typing. So, how can I keep the `EditText` hint until the user types his first letter or number (like in a `SearchView`)?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_search"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search ..."
    android:background="@null"
    />
```

Comment: Use android:hint="Search..." instead of android:text="Search..."

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf did you get a working solution? My hint text becomes floating text once the EditText gains focus. I want it to stay inside the EditText and to disappear once the user starts typing.

Comment: I don't remember, sorry. Would never use anything else than Jetpack Compose though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search...">

    <EditText
          android:id="@+id/text_search"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="Search ..."
          android:background="@null"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```